# Error "context mismatch in svga_sampler_view_destroy" running GUI programs on Ubuntu in a VM

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vmware-player

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a VMware workstation player VM on windows 10. When I run some GUI programs (have observed this on Spyder and Chromium)  am getting the message "context mismatch in svga_sampler_view_destroy" is repeatedly printed to the console.

It seems to be related to virtualization as it goes away if turn off 3D display acceleration. I don't want to  turn off acceleration as it makes a big difference to the video performance.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error while running the [Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) in VmWare player 14.0. This seems to be an issue with Ubuntu, VmWare and OpenGL 3.3

What solved my problem was the solution from [Mesa on how to handle Ubuntu as guest OS](https://www.mesa3d.org/vmware-guest.html) in VmWare

In short you need to set the environment variable `SVGA_VGPU10` to `0` (this turns off OpenGL 3.3 support, falling back to 2.1)

To set it for one session of Bash, use:

```
$ export SVGA_VGPU10=0
```

To permanently write it to the Bash user settings:

```
$ echo "export SVGA_VGPU10=0" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I'm VmWare player 14.0 on ubuntu 17.10 and that didn't solve it for me.

Comment: @user5389726598465 Not stated in the original answer, but this is related to Ubuntu 16.04. I would regardless suggest that you should go with the LTS versions.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference the solution is to disable `Accelerate 3D Graphics`